# PHP in HTML Form - textarea echoing <p>

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea

I've got the following code:

```
<textarea max-length="1000">
<?php echo $field?>
</textarea>
```

This is supposed to be echoing:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Nullam non molestie ligula.
```

but instead I'm getting the raw code:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p><p>Nullam non molestie ligula.</p>
```

I've tried to find a solution but alas the forums have failed me so far! Any ideas?

Comment: You can't put html tags in a textarea it will be represented as raw text. You have to remove them.

Comment: How is `$field` being defined and populated from?

Comment: Thanks! Can I replace them with something to keep the breaks visually tho?

Comment: $field is being read from a mysql database.

Comment: You could probably make use of [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) but if `$field` contains HTML, then you'll need to rethink this.

Comment: Look at `strip_tags()` function ...

Comment: Because of the way the end website is running I can't change the $field to not include html sadly. Otherwise nl2br() would be ideal!

Comment: if your data is not static. you must strip all html tags beside replacing line break with \r\n, for echoing within textarea. or you may use WYSIWYG rich text editor like [TinyMce](http://www.tinymce.com) alternatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Try adding this before echoing $field and after asigning to it the value from MySQL:

```
$field = str_replace("</p><p>", "\n", $field);
$field = str_replace("<p>", "", $field);
$field = str_replace("</p>", "", $field);
```

It's not even by far the most elegant solution but it should work.

Comment: @Kit Happy to hear that. Keep in mind that this will filter and remove only the `<p>` tags while also replacing `<p></p>` with a new line (`\n`)

Answer (score 0):

(Late answer, did not see the accepted answer. Was busy trying to find a solution).

See if this works for you. It has for me.

```
$field = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p><p>Nullam non molestie ligula.</p>';
$newcontent = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "", $field);
$newcontent = str_replace("</p>", "\n\n", $newcontent);

// echo $newcontent;

?>

<textarea max-length="1000">
<?php echo $newcontent;?>
</textarea>
```

HTML source:

```
<textarea max-length="1000">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Nullam non molestie ligula.

</textarea>
```